# Facebook pan page caching clear problem

Tags: php, facebook

It seems that facebook caches fanpage , I am developing FBML application that is displayed in the fan page as a landing tab. But it is just frustrating, anyone has a solution how to clear or prevent facebook fanpage cache or any other way to work with fanpage/application development
?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent the caching on FB's side but a workaround is to use an application within a tab on your fan page that uses the onclick event to load an iframe within the tab to your site, this way the content that is loaded will never be cached as it will be run from your own server.

Comment: This can not be the only solution. It breaks expectations horribly when a single Page Tab App is servicing multiple Pages with customized views. I understand why they do it but they should make valid POST requests with a signed request containing the Page ID to be cached.